# Python Won't Install On Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, python

I'm trying to install Python on my Windows 7 (64-bit) - AMD Sempron Machine. I downloaded the 3.1.2 Windows X86-64 installer. After running it and selecting the option to install it for all users, the installer window disappears. Eventually I get a dialog box error back that says "Installer is no longer responding".

I've also tried the x86 version and the 2.7 amd64.msi.  Any reason why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Are you able to install other MSIs? If not, it's probably an issue with msiexec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to install by right clicking on the installer and selecting "Run as Administrator"?? Even if you disable User Account Control, you still have to run some installers "As Administrator".

Comment: The option to run as administrator doesn't appear in the right-click context menu and is grayed out in properties.  I've also tried running in compatibility mode. Unfortunately the issue remains.

Comment: I also checked my permissions in Windows and I'm a member of the Administrators group.

Comment: Try completely disabling UAC.